# Drupal 8 third level menu item

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have managed to add a 3rd level menu item into Drupal, however I can only see that menu item when I am on the parent page for that item, if I am on another page and view source the code for that menu item does not exist.

I have looked through all of the settings and can not find anyway to change this, what can I do to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Is "Show as expanded" checkbox checked for all parent items?

Comment: There's also "Menu Block" module that offers some more useful options: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, if anyone is wondering you go into Structure > Menus > Main Navigation.

You then click edit on the parent item and check the box that says Show as expanded.

Comment: You didn't figure it out, Stanislav told you about that option.

Comment: I actually didn't see the reply till now, I just stumbled upon it in the backend of Drupal..But thank you Stanislav for your help